# I cant get rid of underlines

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to html so i was trying to make buttons but I cant seem to get rid of the underline in the link. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<style>
body{
background-color: black;
}
a{
border: 5px solid white ;
border-radius: 20px;
font-size: 50px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 600px
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
background-color: black;
padding: 50px
}
a:hover {
color: white;
transition: 0.3s;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 53px;
}

</style>
<title>BUTTON TESTING</title>
<a href=https://www.youtube.com >F.A.Q.</a>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this solves your problem but attribute values in elements should always have single or double quotes around. In your case: `<a href='https://www.youtube.com'>F.A.Q.</a>`

Comment: you gave bottom : 600px ; for <a> it will apply like underline remove that

Comment: you missed semicolon after [bottom: 600px] in anchor styles

Answer (score 2):

In your css code it is missing a semicolon.

```
a{
....
bottom: 600px; //this line
text-decoration: none;
....
padding: 50px; //this line also
}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As other have already stated you are missing the semicolon on the bottom & padding style tags; however, once correcting these the image does not display properly.

You will probably just want to completely remove the `bottom: 600px` as it just seems excessive/unnecessary here.

```css
body{
background-color: black;
}
a{
border: 5px solid white ;
border-radius: 20px;
font-size: 50px;
position: absolute;
//bottom: 600px;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
background-color: black;
padding: 50px;
}
a:hover {
color: white;
transition: 0.3s;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 53px;
}
```

```html
<title>BUTTON TESTING</title>
<a href=https://www.youtube.com >F.A.Q.</a>
```